# Retrieving Metadata information for WCF services in .NET Core

Tags: .net, web-services, wcf, .net-core

Is there a class in .NET Core that corresponds to the *MetadataSet, MetadataImporter or WsdlImporter* class in .Net Framework?

I have several WCF services that I need to interrogate from another application and I need to retrieve information for OperationAction and ReplyAction.

The WCF service address has the format: **http://servicedomain/SimpleServiceName.svc, I also have access to the ?wsdl file**

I need to obtain this information dynamically, without using Visual Studio's proxy connection to WCF services.

Answer (score 0):

**MetadataSet**, **MetadataImporter**, **WsdlImporter**

These three classes come from
**System.ServiceModel.Description**.

**System.ServiceModel** does not support current **.NET core**.

You can nuget **System.ServiceModel.Primitives**.

It can provide libraries for **System.ServiceModel**.
[image]